How can I handle the selection in a Task Pane, AddMRUFilesList function, using MFC?
I want to handle the selection in a Task Pane, AddMRUFilesList function using MFC. I'd think that there would be a function to handle that option. But I can't find one.

CWinApp::AddToRecentFileList maybe?
